# Exit on pressing Enter key (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I have simple code for adding strings into an arraylist. I need to terminate my while loop when user gives a blank input (or clicks enter twice basically).

Here is the code:

```
static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name:");

    String name = sc.nextLine();
    while (!name.equals(" ")) { // ?

        names.add(name);
        name = sc.nextLine();
        if (names.contains(name)) {
            System.out.println(name + " already exists!");
            name = sc.nextLine();
        }

    }
    System.out.println(names);

}
```

Comment: `" "` is not the same as `""`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (!name.equals(" ")) //string containing single space
while (!name.equals(""))  //empty string
while (!name.trim().equals("")) //string empty or with only whitespaces
```

So if you want to terminate on user passing a space or an empty line or ten spaces, use the last option.

Answer (score 2):

Change `while` condition to below:

```
while (!name.trim().equals(""))
```